# Can't Access Stack Exchange Account

Tags: support, user-accounts, stack-exchange-openid

I have several Stack Exchange accounts which I access from the OpenID. Yesterday I changed my password through Stack Overflow account, from a computer, which I usually don't use to access any Stack Exchange account. I successfully changed the password and accessed my account from that account.

Just now I tried to access my account from a different computer, but I'm unable to access it. Password recovery is also not working!

Comment: What exactly is happening? What error you get?

Comment: Have you tried to clear your browser cache?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Nothing happens! that's the more annoying thing! When I enter my username and password and click Sign In nothing happens! (the phrase "Sign in with your...", and the text boxes disappear. and that's it!) I'm not redirected to my home page, 'login' option stays visible in the menu, and so on!

Comment: Most browsers today got dev tools with a Network Profiler among them.. open that profiler and see the traffic, it might give you hint about what is failing.

Comment: No problems in IE 9!   Can anyone please explain me what's wrong with Firefox 16.0.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried clearing the cache like *juergen d* have suggested, but it didn't solved the problem. Then I tried clearing all the cookies, cache, browsing history, ect (**everything!**).  And restarted the browser! Now the problem is solved!